# Laptop won’t recognize charge when it’s on, but will charge when turned off

Tags: bios, ubuntu-16.04, charging, acpi

I noticed my Ubuntu based thinkpad t460 acting very slowly so I rebooted it. However, it failed to boot. So I stuck in a Ubuntu usb and used boot-repair to fix it. I then noticed it would not charge.

I have tried:

rebooting many times

reinstalling Ubuntu clean

trying another AC adapter

pressing the reset button on the back

turning off the internal battery and rebooting

fiddling around with acpi in grub

fiddling around in bios boot options

Strangely enough, it will charge when turned off which leads me to think it might be a problem with the charging port. However it will not even recognize the ac adapter when it’s on (power management says it’s not plugged in).

Is this likely a charging port/motherboard problem? Or something to do with boot repair?

Comment: Type `upower --monitor` at terminal and see what changes in output on plugging and removing the AC. That will help to point out the exact problem.

Comment: It doesn’t register anything. However, I’ve confirmed that it can charge offline. But when I plug it in, the power button flashes 3 times, so at the hardware level it seems to recognize it’s plugged in.

Comment: Similarly, if I take the external battery out and disable the internal one in BIOS, it will reboot when I plug in the adapter, like it should.